# Shiny fileInput problems with big filesize

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Hey guys I hope you can help me with that,

I am building a shiny application where I have to upload two big files. The files are of the size 600 MB and 225 MB. To increase the possible size of my upload I have used
`options(shiny.maxRequestSize=1e9)`, so I can upload files with a size from up to 1 GB
. Offline my application is working just fine. However, on the Shiny server the fileInput has a problem after slowly uploading the desired file. After some minutes the fileInput looks like this
[fileInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmwhW.png). There are no logs which could me help to find the problem. It has definitely to do with the file size but since I increased the upload size it should just work fine. I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: Instead of `1e9`, try `1000*1024^2`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it still won't work.